# Error on connecting to host on same network iOS 14.4 flutter

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, dart

I'm facing an issue when I try to connect to a server on my local network (192.168.1.12). The log prints

> SocketException: Connection failed (OS Error: No route to host, errno = 65), address = 192.168.1.12, port = 9000

However if I change the route to another domain like https://www.google.com there is no problem. (Despite that google.com doesn't have an API REST). My guess is if it could be a local network error or similar. Because from my iOS browser I'm able to connect to the server.

I've been working with Flutter and iOS 14.4. And my app and server are in the same local network. Also I've tried with the computer's name but no luck

Comment: Just to be sure, are you using http://192.168.1.12:9000 or only 192.168.1.12? 
I get such issues sometimes when I do not enter http in the url.

Comment: You cannot connect from one device to another device using a local IP address, when these devices are not on the same network. Local (or private) IP addresses are only visible within the local network. So, Simulator - your Server should work. However, iPhone over Wifi to your local IP address on your Mac cannot work.

Comment: when I do the http connection is in this case http://192.168.1.12:9000/api/v1/signin

Comment: I'm on the same local network

Comment: using Bonjour, maybe. Get your local computer name (Preferences -> Sharing) and try `http://your-computer-name.local.:9000/`. See also: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/6205

Comment: I just tried but no luck, it's too weird because from my browser works perfect. Could not be iOS 14.4? Besides that works perfect if I point to a public api